# How can i replace mule eventContext?

Tags: java, mule

I have three config files in one process

they all have `vm://BOUNDPATH` inbounds.

when it runs i put the context to a cache all three of them

i can route to any config by getting the context in the cache

i am using this code using a component

```
DefaultLocalMuleClient client = (DefaultLocalMuleClient) mContext.getClient();
client.send("vm://BOUNDPATH", msg)
```

is worked fine.

But, i want to route with out `client.send`

```
vm:outbound-endpoint address="vm://BOUNDPATH" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
```

like this by overriding or replacing the eventcontext is this possible ?

thanks.

Comment: Sorry but you're question makes no sense to me. What's the issue when you use the `vm:outbound-endpoint` instead of code?

Comment: Hm .. i have three config files named grp1, chan1 and chan2. grp1 routes to chan1 or chan2 by the data it receives. if the data is for chan1 i get cha1 context from cache and route by using client.send. My issue is for personal reason i can't use client.send so i want to use  vm:outbound-endpoint but chan1 or chan2 are in another config file so i have to make vm:outbound-endpoint route to the contex i have get from cache. I want to replace grp1 context to chan1 context when i use vm:outbound-endpoint is this possible ?

Comment: If all these config files are in the same app, the answer is yes.

Comment: They all are in the same app. Can you show me how ?

Comment: Use standard `vm:outbound-endpoint` but prefer using the `path` attribute instead of the `address` one.

Comment: This should help: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference#VMTransportReference-Outboundendpoint

Comment: Sorry for asking to much T ^ T .. If a use ref in my outbound-endpoint, in my java code what shoud i implement or extend ?

Comment: I just want access to the context and replace it by the contex i have got from the cache ..

Comment: I have tried to use vm:connector and used <services-overrides outboundTransformer="myClass"/> i extended OutboundAppendTransformer and override method setMuleContext. I set the context i have get from the cache but it's not working ...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve then. Are you trying to send messages from Java code without using the Mule Client? Using the Mule Client is the best way to do it so I really don't get the point.